# Select line item from list and push to array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to allow users to select certain items from a list and add them into an array. I'm struggling with my with array.push(). Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a = [];
    
    $("#b1").click(function(){
       $("#l1").hide();
       a.push($("this").text());
    });
    
    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>
<style> span {color: red;} </style>
Array of Selected Items- <span ID="s"></span>
<ul>
 <li ID="l1"><div ID="d1"><button ID="b1">Select</button>One</div></li>
 <li><div ID="d2"><button ID="b2">Select</button>Two</div></li>
 <li><div ID="d3"><button ID="b3">Select</button>Three</div></li>
 <li><div ID="d4"><button ID="b4">Select</button>Four</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Here is the link to my code in Tryit Editor:
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBXZFMRGMUAE

Comment: I used a bit of the information from all of the answers and resolved it using class instead of ID and used next() instead of closest.  Here is the working code http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBY4H08S45YF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following code should work for you as expected
You have to work with `class` selector instead of id so you can bind all buttons to single event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = [];

    $(".btn").click(function(){
       $(this).parent("li").hide();
       a.push($("this").text());
    });

    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );
});


<body>
<style> span {color: red;} </style>
Array of Selected Items- <span ID="s"></span>
<ul>
    <li ID="l1"><div ID="d1"><button class="btn" ID="b1">Select</button>One</div></li>
    <li><div ID="d2"><button  class="btn" ID="b2">Select</button>Two</div></li>
    <li><div ID="d3"><button class="btn" ID="b3">Select</button>Three</div></li>
    <li><div ID="d4"><button class="btn" ID="b4">Select</button>Four</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of $(this) is inside a click handler for a button, so it refers to the button.  Maybe use $(this).closest("li") instead

Also your line to update the text of #s is not inside your click handler... Not sure if you intended that to update on each button-click?

And as K D points out below, if you want all of your buttons to work you shouldn't attach the .click() handler to just one using the id #b1. You should do $("button").click( ... )

Answer (score 1):

I moved your SCRIPT block to the document HEAD and changed the .click to .on and its working now here: [copy of your original code to test](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBY11ACCK5JK)

```
// note the difference from your original .click, 
// not sure if this was a problem per se, but this is what I usually do.
$("#b1").on('click', function(){
   $("#l1").hide();
   a.push($(this).text());
   console.log(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` and get the `text` of the closest `div`

```
$("button").click(function(){
       a.push($(this).closest("div").text());
       $(this).closest("li").hide();
       $( "#s" ).text( a.join(" ") );
    });
```